# Having Multiple Values to One Key in a Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am having trouble adding multiple values to one key, I am wanting to have my dictionary d have a key of "county" and for each county to have as many values as are in my college_cities dictionary. Thanks in advance!

```
from geopy.distance import distance

college_towns = {

    'Stillwater': (36.125074,  -97.072201),
    'Norman': (35.194525, -97.444354),
    'Edmond': (35.656744, -97.470951)

}

counties = {

    'Adair':    (35.8975,   -94.651671),
    'Alfalfa':  (36.729703, -98.323445),
    'Atoka':    (34.374813, -96.034705),
    'Beaver':   (36.748334, -100.483056),
    'Beckham':  (35.273945, -99.671638),
    'Blaine':   (35.877782, -98.428934),
    'Bryan':    (33.964004, -96.264137),
    'Caddo':    (35.16792,  -98.381045),
    'Canadian': (35.543416, -97.979836),
    'Carter':   (34.251848, -97.287927),
    'Cherokee': (35.904367, -94.996796),
    'Choctaw':  (34.027645, -95.554208),
    'Cimarron': (36.755276, -102.508735),
    'Cleveland':    (35.203117, -97.328332),
    'Coal': (34.582861, -96.288039),
    'Comanche': (34.662628, -98.476597),
    'Cotton':   (34.290676, -98.373438),
    'Craig':    (36.76389,  -95.201553),
    'Creek':    (35.907732, -96.379793),
    'Custer':   (35.645601, -98.997386),
    'Delaware': (36.393369, -94.808206),
    'Dewey':    (35.978433, -99.014094),
    'Ellis':    (36.224258, -99.750139),
    'Garfield': (36.378273, -97.787729),
    'Garvin':   (34.70935,  -97.312723),
    'Grady':    (35.021058, -97.88689),
    'Grant':    (36.788254, -97.788151),
    'Greer':    (34.935263, -99.552968),
    'Harmon':   (34.745971, -99.844194),
    'Harper':   (36.800456, -99.662842),
    'Haskell':  (35.232294, -95.109578),
    'Hughes':   (35.052934, -96.251183),
    'Jackson':  (34.593949, -99.41221),
    'Jefferson':    (34.105092, -97.838814),
    'Johnston': (34.313455, -96.654255),
    'Kay':  (36.814842, -97.143755),
    'Kingfisher':   (35.949431, -97.934568),
    'Kiowa':    (34.921489, -98.981617),
    'Latimer':  (34.875137, -95.272263),
    'Le Flore': (34.899642, -94.703491),
    'Lincoln':  (35.703118, -96.881392),
    'Logan':    (35.914151, -97.450764),
    'Love': (33.957775, -97.245124),
    'McClain':  (35.016414, -97.449811),
    'McCurtain':    (34.117073, -94.766086),
    'McIntosh': (35.369092, -95.671764),
    'Major':    (36.313119, -98.542015),
    'Marshall': (34.027007, -96.770533),
    'Mayes':    (36.303804, -95.235638),
    'Murray':   (34.485766, -97.071557),
    'Muskogee': (35.617551, -95.383911),
    'Noble':    (36.384901, -97.236335),
    'Nowata':   (36.789615, -95.613312),
    'Okfuskee': (35.466804, -96.327762),
    'Oklahoma': (35.554611, -97.409401),
    'Okmulgee': (35.646879, -95.96458),
    'Osage':    (36.62468,  -96.408385),
    'Ottawa':   (36.835764, -94.802681),
    'Pawnee':   (36.313704, -96.696669),
    'Payne':    (36.079225, -96.975255),
    'Pittsburg':    (34.92554,  -95.74813),
    'Pontotoc': (34.721071, -96.692738),
    'Pottawatomie': (35.211393, -96.957007),
    'Pushmataha':   (34.377896, -95.408085),
    'Roger Mills':  (35.708554, -99.741572),
    'Rogers':   (36.378082, -95.601337),
    'Seminole': (35.158366, -96.602858),
    'Sequoyah': (35.502435, -94.750757),
    'Stephens': (34.481361, -97.855607),
    'Texas':    (36.741964, -101.488434),
    'Tillman':  (34.371085, -98.931701),
    'Tulsa':    (36.120121, -95.941731),
    'Wagoner':  (35.963479, -95.5141),
    'Washington':   (36.70438,  -95.906155),
    'Washita':  (35.290177, -98.991962),
    'Woods':    (36.765141, -98.868967),
    'Woodward': (36.425619, -99.273661)

}
for city, coords in college_towns.items():
    d = {
        'county': coords
    }

for county, coord in counties.items():
    for city, coords in college_towns.items():
        d[county] = distance(coord, coords).miles
        print(county, d[county])
```

My current output is:

```
Adair 136.4922891469114
Adair 164.6391572270637
Adair 159.25535744806874
Alfalfa 81.23353285605839
Alfalfa 116.75075510750989
Alfalfa 87.9928638267299
Atoka 134.16552438092384
Atoka 98.07963763791889
Atoka 120.18011702380218
.....
```

I would prefer if it would list the county and then the corresponding three distance values as opposed to repeating three times.

Comment: Take a look at `collections.defaultdict`.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {
    county: {
        town: distance(county_pos, town_pos).miles
            for town, town_pos in college_towns.items()
    } for county, county_pos in counties.items()
}
```

Keys of `d` are counties, keys of inner dictionaries are college towns. You access this like:

```
d['Adair']['Norman'] # distance Adair-Norman
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would prefer if it would list the county and then the corresponding three distance values as opposed to repeating three times.

If that is the only thing you need to do differently, then the title of the question is a little misleading. You can just rearrange the output of print

```
for county, coord in counties.items():
    print(county, " distance to")
    for city, coords in college_towns.items():
        d[county] = distance(coord, coords).miles
        print(" " * 4, city, " is ", d[county], " miles")
```